# Inside a catch clause, how can I see an exception without a name

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Occasionally I find myself debugging through some code like this:

```
try
{
    GetResult(new DTO());
}
catch
{
    Response.Write(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "<p>Unable to get result</p>"));
}
```

While I'm debugging, I set a breakpoint on `Response.Write` but, since the exception has no name, I can't find out anything about it. How can I view information on this swallowed exception?

Comment: Of course, any code that looks like this in the first place needs to be replaced immediately...

Comment: Agreed. Why the downvotes? I don't believe a duplicate is grounds for a downvote (since I searched and couldn't find the other question, I hope this one can be a good pointer to it) and I believe the question itself is of average quality.

Comment: @sirdank The downvotes are due to lack of "research effort". I did not personally downvote, but I found the duplicate by searching for "debug exception no variable" and it is clearly a highly upvoted Q+A.. Every other link I found, as reiterated by DavidG, urges you not to do this exact thing. Self-answered questions of usefulness are always welcome, however this question in particular has been covered, and is not good practice.

Answer (score 3):

Inside VS 2017, at least, you can open Debug -> Windows -> Watch -> Watch 1 and set a watch on a variable named `$exception`.